# How to find out who created aws cloudwatch alarm/metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

How do I find out what IAM user created certain metrics and alarms?

I tried CLI commands: `describe-alarms` and `list-metrics` and they don't seem to provide this information nor when looking at the configuration for the alarms and metrics in the AWS console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While users call APIs to create resources in AWS, those resources are associated with the AWS Account rather than a user. As long as a user has permission to create resources in the account, the resources will be created/viewed/deleted.

However, you can use [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) to **retrieve information about the API calls themselves**:

> AWS CloudTrail is an AWS service that helps you enable governance, compliance, and operational and risk auditing of your AWS account. Actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service are recorded as events in CloudTrail. Events include actions taken in the AWS Management Console, AWS Command Line Interface, and AWS SDKs and APIs.